# Simulate post in grails - spring authetication

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm trying to do a post to this standard spring url, to simulate an authentication:

http://www.whateverAddress.is:8080/Test/j_spring_security_check

If I use the plug-in poster it works fine, I put two parameters j_username and j_password and an header parameter X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest and indeed I got in return a json result.

If I try to do it by code in Java, tons of examples in Google, it seems not to work. At the moment I'm using this code but I get nothing in return:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "username"));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "password"))
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.whateverAddress.is:8080/Test/j_spring_security_check");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
        httpPost.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(responseString);
```

If I print the response,(not the entity) I have the following:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Set-Cookie: grails_remember_me=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/Test, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=247CF8B70D589F053DE4C937F2E16B9D; Path=/Test/; HttpOnly, Location: http://www.whateverAddress.is:8080/Test/login/authfail?ajax=true, Content-Length: 0, Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 12:04:12 GMT]

Which is code 302, like I have been redirected instead of having code 200 and the json, as Poster plugin shows me.

**UPDATE**
I create a button which fire up an ajax post request, as I should be able to do from java code side,  here the code:

```
   $(function() {
    $('#btnPush').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.whateverAddress.is:8080/Test/j_spring_security_check',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                j_username: 'username',
                j_password: 'password'
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('Success!!!');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Fail!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Looking at the request sent, I see the header and the JSON received, everything is fine. If I replicate the same header in the java side still nothing happen. I miss something

**LAST UPDATE - CLOSE**
Basically once the post is done we need to follow the redirect with the auth cookie to get the right information:

```
        def headers = ["X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"]
        def postParams = ["j_username": user, "j_password": pwd]
        def url = "http://www.whatever.is:8080/test/j_spring_security_check"
        def returnstring = doHttpPost(url, postParams, headers)

    private String doHttpPost(String url, Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> headers) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient()
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url)
    String result

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>()

        headers?.each {
            post.setHeader(it.key, it.value)
        }

        params?.each {
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(it.key, it.value))
        }

        if (params) {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters))
        }

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post)

        if (response.getStatusLine()?.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            result = response.getEntity().getContent()?.text
        }

        if (response.getStatusLine()?.getStatusCode() == 302) {
            String redirectUrl = response.getHeaders("Location")?.value[0]
            result = doHttpGet(redirectUrl, ["Cookie": response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")?.value[0]])
        }

       } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex)
       } finally {
        post.getEntity().consumeContent()
        return result
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are being redirected to `loginUrl` after the login attempt. The Security Servlet/Filter doesn't seem to recognize that the request was sent as an AJAX one. Try adding more headers to make the server recognize it correctly.

Comment: I try to replicate the same header but no luck

Comment: you are using 2 different urls: "http://localhost:8080/SkiBook/j_spring_security_check" and 'http://www.whateverAddress.is:8080/Test/j_spring_security_check'

Comment: You are right sorry, fix it. it was just for the sake of the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be using android SDK for calling. This is what I'm using to POST data to the REST API (powered by Grails):

```
HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParams.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "j_username", "username" ) );
postParams.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "j_password", "password" ) )
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( url );
httppost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( postParams, HTTP.UTF_8 ) );
httpPost.addHeader( "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" );
HttpResponse hr = httpClient.execute( httppost );
JSONObject res = readStreamUsingReader( hr );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is a much better code. I update my original post. Unfortunately, even if I got a reply from the server, I'm still not able to get the json I should. See my original post. thanks a lot